# Por que relações no Entity Framework code first são apontadas com ICollection<T>?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, code-first

Por que relações no Entity Framework code first são apontadas com ICollection? Qual a melhor instanciação(?) para a propriedade em casos comuns? List?
A utilização da palavra-chave virtual é apenas para habilitar lazy loading na propriedade?

Answer (score 6):

## Por que relações no Entity Framework code first são apontadas com ICollection?

Porque a carga preguiçosa do Entity Framework coloca nesta propriedade um proxy dinâmico, que representa um objeto que implementa `ICollection` mas que na bem da verdade não é bem uma coleção de coisa alguma.

Ao acessar essa propriedade, o proxy dinâmico é substituído aí sim por uma coleção de verdade (normalmente `List<>`).

## Qual a melhor instanciação (?) para a propriedade em casos comuns?

Da seguinte forma:

```
public virtual ICollection<Objeto> Objetos { get; set; }
```

## A utilização da palavra-chave virtual é apenas para habilitar lazy loading na propriedade?

Não. `virtual` indica que o objeto pode receber derivados da classe genérica. Por exemplo, você declara um Model chamado `Alimento` e outro chamado `Fruta`, e faz `Fruta` derivar `Alimento`. Declarando desta forma:

```
public virtual ICollection<Alimento> Alimentos { get; set; }
```

`Alimentos` pode conter também objetos da classe `Fruta`.

[Leia mais sobre o modificador `virtual` aqui](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/9fkccyh4.aspx).