# Dúvida com EntityFramework CodeFirst

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Estou iniciando em Entity Framework e estou com uma dúvida referente ao *CodeFirst*. Por que eu tenho que usar como virtual algumas propriedades como o exemplo abaixo?

```
[Table("Grupo")]
public class Grupo
{
   public int ID { get; set; }
   [Required(ErrorMessage="Nome não pode ser branco.")]
   public string Nome { get; set; }

   public virtual IQueryable<Produto> Produtos { get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Por dois motivos:

1. Porque é o Entity Framework que monta este objeto pra você;
2. Porque ele não necessariamente é uma lista ou uma coleção. Ele pode ser um Proxy Dinâmico, que faz o procedimento de carga preguiçosa do *Framework*. [Explico isso aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/60932/duvida-sobre-implementa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-lazy-load-e-dependency-injection/60982#60982) [e também aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/46054/por-que-rela%C3%A7%C3%B5es-no-entity-framework-code-first-s%C3%A3o-apontadas-com-icollectiont/46076#46076)

Isto está incorreto:

```
public virtual IQueryable<Produto> Produtos { get; set; }
```

[`IQueryable<>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.linq.iqueryable(v=vs.110).aspx) é um objeto que pode avaliar uma lista, e não uma lista de fato. [Isto está explicado com mais detalhes aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17284/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-ienumerable-iqueryable-e-list).

O correto é:

```
public virtual ICollection<Produto> Produtos { get; set; }
```

Comment: Boa noite Cigado, desculpe a minha ignorância. Eu não entendi o significado do que seria um Proxy Dinâmico. E sobre o virtual, quer dizer então que ele não é o responsável por fazer a associação entre as entidades, ou seja, as classes? Outra dúvida, tem que ser sempre usada a interface ICollection ou pode ser usada também IEnumerable? Grata!

Comment: Proxy Dinâmico é uma classe que finge ser outra. No caso da carga preguiçosa, ao invés de ser carregada uma lista de Produtos, é colocado na inicialização de um `Grupo` um Proxy Dinâmico que finge ser uma lista de Produtos. Esses Produtos só serão carregados efetivamente quando você chamar essa lista de alguma forma (no ASP.NET MVC, normalmente é em *View*). Aí sim o EF carrega os Produtos do banco pra você.

Comment: Sobre ser `ICollection` ou `IEnumerable`, até funciona pra `IEnumerable`, mas `ICollection` tem alguns recursos a mais, sendo uma interface mais abrangente. Por isso minha recomendação.

Comment: @KellySoares Recomendo você fazer outra pergunta e marcar esta como aceita, se ela resolveu sua dúvida.