# Identificando a chave estrangeira no Entity Framework CodeFirst

Tags: entity-framework

O Entity Framework identifica a chave estrangeira através de propriedades que possuem Id como parte do nome ou pelo Data Annotation [Key]. Minha dúvida é, como ele identifica as chaves estrangeiras e faz o relacionamento entre outra tabela?

```
public class Predio {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public Endereco Endereco { get; set; }
}

public class Construtora {
    public Construtora()
    {
        this.Predios = new List<Predio>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string RegistroCivil { get; set; }
    public List<Predio> Predios { get; set; }
}

[ComplexType()]
public class Endereco {
    public string Logradouro { get; set; }
    public string Numero { get; set; }
    public string Bairro { get; set; }
    public string Cidade { get; set; }
    public string CEP { get; set; }
}

public class Contexto : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Predio> Predios { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Construtora> Construtoras { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Objetivamente falando, [através de uma classe chamada `ForeignKeyPropertyDiscoveryConvention`](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/fd1ee9d3b7ade1c3f0456a5260926f72376447eb/src/EntityFramework.Core/Metadata/Conventions/Internal/ForeignKeyPropertyDiscoveryConvention.cs). [O funcionamento é explicado aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx).

Grosso modo, a maneira que o Entity Framework realiza a descoberta da chave estrangeira é da seguinte forma (considere que várias dessas etapas usam [*Reflection*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms173183(v=VS.120).aspx)):

1. É verificado no *Model* se há propriedades de navegação compatíveis. Por exemplo:

   ```cs
   public virtual EntidadeEstrangeira EntidadeEstrangeira { get; set; }
   ```
2. Se sim, é verificado no *Model* se há alguma propriedade candidata a ser o componente de informação dessa chave estrangeira. Por exemplo:

   ```cs
   public int EntidadeEstrangeiraId { get; set; }
   ```

   2.1. Pode acontecer desse campo não ser localizado. Se não for, o Entity Framework tenta procurar por alguma propriedade que esteja marcada com o [`ForeignKeyAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.foreignkeyattribute(v=vs.110).aspx). Este *Attribute* pode decorar tanto uma propriedade de navegação quanto uma propriedade de dados. Por exemplo:

   ```cs
   [ForeignKey("EntidadeEstrangeira")]
   public int OutroNomeDeEntidadeEstrangeiraQualquerId { get; set; }
   ```

   ou ainda:

   ```cs
   [ForeignKey("EntidadeEstrangeiraId")]
   public virtual EntidadeEstrageira UmNomeQualquerDePropriedadeDeNavegacao { get; set; }
   ```
3. Ainda, é verificado se existe alguma anotação de *Fluent API* no contexto. Por lá é possível também configurar chaves estrangeiras.

Não vou entrar em pormenores do funcionamento porque é bastante coisa, mas em linhas gerais, é isso.

---

## Seu Caso

Vou analisar as entidades uma a uma.

```cs
public class Predio {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public Endereco Endereco { get; set; }
}
```

Este é um caso clássico que cai na primeira etapa. Normalmente o padrão é `virtual` para propriedades de navegação ([expliquei isso aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80248/d%c3%bavida-com-entityframework-codefirst)).

Como você não definiu a chave estrangeira, **se o objeto não fosse um tipo complexo**, o Entity Framework definiria uma chave estrangeira pra você na tabela correspondente ao *Model* `Predio`. Se não me engano, ficaria `Endereco_Id`.

No entanto, você definiu `Endereco` como um objeto complexo. Como a relação é de 1 para 1, no fundo é como se você estivesse definindo uma extensão de `Predio`. Repare como ficou o esquema ao gerar a *Migration*:

```cs
    CreateTable(
            "dbo.Predios",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Nome = c.String(),
                    Endereco_Logradouro = c.String(),
                    Endereco_Numero = c.String(),
                    Endereco_Bairro = c.String(),
                    Endereco_Cidade = c.String(),
                    Endereco_CEP = c.String(),
                    Construtora_Id = c.Int(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Construtoras", t => t.Construtora_Id)
            .Index(t => t.Construtora_Id);
```

Observe também que você não definiu uma propriedade para `Construtora_Id`, mas realizando a leitura do *Model* `Construtora`, que possui uma relação de 1 para N com `Predio`, o Entity Framework concluiu que seria necessário uma chave estrangeira aí, e a definiu como `Construtora_Id` (regras 1 e 2, acima).

Por fim, este construtor não tem utilidade:

```cs
public Construtora()
{
    this.Predios = new List<Predio>();
}
```

`Predios` é definida na carga de dados de `Construtora` automaticamente. Não é preciso inicializá-la.

Comment: Cigano, no exemplo que postei eu não defini como virtual e nem decorei nada na entidade Construtora com o Data Annotation [ForeignKey()], foi utilizado Fluent API neste contexto?

Comment: @KellySoares Então, algumas construções ali estão um pouco problemáticas. Se for do seu desejo, posso comentá-las uma a uma.

Comment: Eu adoraria, porque a princípio, eu achei que fosse por causa do construtor da classe Construtora que está passando uma referência a entidade Prédios, achei que isso é que estava fazendo o relacionamento entre as entidades.

Comment: @KellySoares Atualizei a resposta.